# Prove by induction with summation and factorials

Tags: induction

Sorry I'm not sure how to format the text for using sum. Could someone help me out with that as well. Much appreciated.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{r=1}^{n} (r^2+1)r! =n(n+1)!
\end{eqnarray*}
for all $n \geq 1 $.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{r=1}^{n+1} (r^2+1)r! &=& \sum_{r=1}^{n} (r^2+1)r! +((n+1)^2+1)(n+1)! \\ &=&n(n+1)!+((n+1)^2+1)(n+1)! \\&=&(n^2+3n+2)(n+1)!=(n+1)(n+2)!
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Notice that $n(n+1)!-(n-1)n!=\left(n^2+1\right)n!$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} (r^2+1)r! =n(n+1)!$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{1} (r^2+1)r! = (1^2 + 1)1! = 2 * 1 = 2 = 1(1 + 1)$$
So it is true for $n=1$. Now let's see for $n=p$
$$\sum_{r=1}^p (r^2+1)r! =p(p+1)!$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{p+1} (r^2+1)r! = (p+1)(p+2)!$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{p} (r^2+1)r! + ((p+1)^2 + 1)(p+1)! = (p+1)(p+1)! *(p+2)$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{p} (r^2+1)r! + (p^2 + 2p + 2)(p+1)! = (p+1)(p+2)(p+1)!$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{p} (r^2+1)r! + (p^2 + 2p + 2)(p+1)! = (p^2 + 3p + 2)(p+1)!$$
$$\sum_{r=1}^{p} (r^2+1)r! + (p^2 + 2p + 2)(p+1)! = (p + 3 + 2 * \frac{1}{p})p(p+1)!$$
$$1 + ((p^2 + 2p + 2)(p+1)!)/(p(p+1)!) = (p + 3 + 2\frac{1}{p})$$
$$\frac{p^2 + 2p + 2}{p} + 1 = p + 3 + 2 * \frac{1}{p}$$
$$p + 2 + 2 * \frac{1}{p} + 1 = p + 3 + 2 * \frac{1}{p}$$

Which is true, so the statement is true, proven by induction